# Checking if a connection to an IRC server is established

Tags: c#, irc

Basically, my intention is to get my IRC Bot to only send a message when it is actually connected properly (this is the message used to identify it to the nickserv) however I am unsure on how to check if the connection has been established. If anyone has any information which could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using a 3rd party library or else you wouldn't be asking this.. So which library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your connection is active, the server sends you a `001` (`RPL_WELCOME`) numeric.  You can send your nickserv login in response to this.